# how to read char array from serial monitor and command arduino accordingly?

Tags: arduino

currently, I am working on a project to read char inputs from serial monitor and command Arduino to switch on/off specific pins. The problem I am facing is, I am unable to read the complete char array entered in the serial monitor. can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
#define X 13 //led pin

char txt[15]; 
int i; 
int Status=0;

void setup() {   // put your setup code here, to run once:  
pinMode(X,OUTPUT);// setting the pin flow of control as output

 Serial.begin(9600);  
 while(!Serial)   
 {
    ;  //to wait for pc to connect  
 }   
 Serial.println("\nHome Automation");   
 dashprint();  


}

void loop() {   // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:  
if(Serial.available()>0)    
{   i=0;
    while(Serial.available()>0)   //if serial available
    { char inchar=Serial.read();
      txt[i]=inchar; // add char to txt string
      i++;// increment to where to write next
      txt[i]='\0'; //null termination

     }    
  Serial.print(txt);    
  check();
  } 
  }

void dashprint() //to print dashes 
{
Serial.println("-----------------------------------------------");  
Serial.println("give me some command"); //ask for command    
  }

void check() 
{    if(strncmp(txt,"ON",2)==0)   
      {
         digitalWrite(X,HIGH);
         Status=1;
          }   
      else if(strncmp(txt,"OFF",3)==0)  
       { digitalWrite(X,LOW);
         Status=0;
          }   
      else if(txt=="STATUS")  
       { 
           } 
      else Serial.println("ERROR");
   }
```

output:

### Home Automation

give me some command
OERROR
NERROR

ERROR

expected output:

### Home Automation

give me some command
ON

Comment: Can you describe your issue with some more detail? For instance, what are you expecting and what are you getting? Provide concrete examples. Please read the help documentation, particularly on [how to as a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: I am expecting Arduino to read the char array, compare it, and turn the led on/off. what happening is, Arduino reads single char rather reading the whole array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arduino is too fast to read the text "ON" in one round.

9600 is 1 ms per character.
A simple workaround is, to add a little delay

```
if(Serial.available()>0) {
    delay(3); // wait for the whole message
    i=0;
    while(Serial.available()>0)  {
       ...
```

ADD:
Additionally, you obviously receive a '\n' (newline) character. Make sure it's not causing troubles.

And increase the delay or have a better approach in general, if you expect more than 3 characters ( "STATUS" )

Answer (score 0):

```
struct MYObject {char a[256];};     
//structure works well with EEPROM put and get functions.  
//also lets to input large strings, more then 64 bytes, as http     
void setup() {    
MYObject str ={" "};    
Serial.begin(115200);     
while (!Serial.available()) delay (10); //wait for string   
int i = 0;  
int k= Serial.available();  
while (k  > 0){     
char inchar = Serial.read();  //read one by one character    
str.a[i] = inchar;               
i++;    
if (k < 3) delay (10); //it gives possibility to collect more characters on stream    
k = Serial.available();     
}     
str.a[i]='\0'; //null terminator     
//now lets see result      
Serial.println(str.a);     
//.....      
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to include any piece of reference, advice and guidelines here. Code-only answers give a solution but not really an answer.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.